# Eclipse crashes then the process cant be ended

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using eclipse to run a maven project I'm working on.  Lately I've been starting it up and in the middle of building the maven projects it closes itself.  There are only a few maven projects, so it shouldn't be a memory problem.  This has just started happening lately.  When I try to reopen it the message stating my workbench is already in use comes up.  So I go to kill the process, eclipse.exe, and although I click yes when it asks if I'm sure I want to stop it, the process is still active in task manager.  The only way to get rid of it is to restart my computer.  Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the Java process instead of ecelipse.